# python django smart-selects is not working properly

Tags: python, django, django-smart-selects

I have install `django-smart-selects` but when i add the url in the `urls.py`

```
url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
```

when i run my application after this
i got this error

> from django.utils.encoding import force_text ImportError: cannot
> import name 'force_text' from 'django.utils.encoding'

so here in `django.utils.encoding` I didn't find any import `force_text` so I change it to `force_str`.

I am using django 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your system libraries, edit this files:

- .../smart_selects/form_fields.py
- .../smart_selects/utils.py
- .../smart_selects/widgets.py

change: force_text.
to: force_str

Then, edit this file:

- .../smart_selects/urls.py

change:  from django.conf.urls import url
to: from django.urls import re_path
change: url(...
to: re_path(...

in your project folder, edit urls.py

from django.urls import include, path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
...
re_path(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')),
...
]